# Pyspark Specify Default Value for Column

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm using Spark 1.6.1 and Python 2.7

I'm trying to figure out how I can specify a default value for a newly added column to a dataframe. Take this scenario where I have a dataframe named df1 that contains

```
+-------+----+
|user_id| age|
+-------+----+
|  10000|  45|
|  10013|  40|
|  10021|Null|
|  10025|  50|
|  10051|  31|
+-------+----+
```

Now I want to add a new column called age2 that just has a simple function age + 1

```
>>> df1 = df1.withColumn("age2", df1["age"]+1)

+-------+----+----+
|user_id| age|age2|
+-------+----+----+
|  10000|  45|  46|
|  10013|  40|  41|
|  10021|Null|Null|
|  10025|  50|  51|
|  10051|  31|  32|
+-------+----+----+
```

Is there a way I can specify a default value for age2 so that instead of returning a null for age2 when there is a null in age, I can return something like 1 so that I get

```
+-------+----+----+
|user_id| age|age2|
+-------+----+----+
|  10000|  45|  46|
|  10013|  40|  41|
|  10021|Null|   1|
|  10025|  50|  51|
|  10051|  31|  32|
+-------+----+----+
```

I know that I can use a UDF to do this, but I want to know if there is a built in way to do it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `fillna` function. Create a new column as you are doing it currently. Next fill the null values with the [fillna function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna)

```
>>> df1 = df1.withColumn("age2", df1["age"]+1)
>>> df1 = df1.na.fill({'age2': 1})
```